# Нет подходящей функции для вызова. В некоторых компиляторах

Tags: qt, qt5, компилятор

В компиляторах Qt 5.6 и 5.7 выдаёт ошибку указанную ниже, в компиляторе 4.8.7 такой ошибки нет в чём может быть проблема?

```
error: no matching function for call to 'TaskConfig::clrMail(QStringList&, int&)'
       str = clrMail(list, i);
                            ^

TaskConfig::TaskConfig(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
QStringList TaskConfig::isMailBase()
{
  QStringList list;
  QString str;
  int size = list.size();
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
      str = clrMail(list, i); // ОШИБКА ТУТ
      list_result << str;
    }
  return list_result;
}
QString TaskConfig::clrMail(QString list, int x)
{
  QString buf = list.at(x);
  buf.trimmed();
  return buf;
}

#ifndef TASKCONFIG_H
#define TASKCONFIG_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDateTime>

class TaskConfig : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit TaskConfig(QObject *parent = 0);

  QStringList isMailBase();


signals:

public slots:

private:
  QString clrMail(QString, int);

};

#endif // TASKCONFIG_H
```

Comment: А версии компиляторов одинаковые?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, Qt x.x.x это версия библиотеки, а не компилятора. Во-вторых, этот код нигде не может работать, т.к. у Вас есть функция, которая первым аргументом принимает `QString`, а Вы туда передаёте `QStringList`.

Ваша функция должна выглядеть так:

```
QString clrMail(QStringList, int);
```

Comment: Иногда поражаюсь своей внимательности и твёрдому чувству уверенности в том что я прав, и это не смотря на то, что здравый смысл подсказывал, что проблема решается небольшим увеличением внимательности.